# Is there a name for this type of optimization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, data-structures

I work on a large code base and when profiling most of time is spent simply in lock contention and doing lookups in maps.  The system is a real time system driven by callbacks from an incoming data stream.  Many threads get the callbacks. ( many consumers ).

Typically callback function gets called with a string (the key ) and then many functions are called from the callback. And those functions themselves call many functions.

Many of these functions or children of these functions do lookup, typically looking up same string each time.  ( The string initially that was passed into callback ).

The obvious optimization is to do lookup once and then pass along what was found down call chain as parameter.  But problem is this would involve changing huge amount of code, and function signatures.

So one solution is at callback function save the lookup value in global structure mapping threadid to lookup value.  Threadid is an int and number of threads less than 100 so looking up thread id is quicker than string lookup.

Is there a name for this technique ? It is like a thread cache that is cleared at top of call chain.

Comment: I don't know how open you are to design changes, but an even _faster_ solution in the same vein would be to use _[thread-local variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local)_ declared with the keyword `thread_local`. Then you don't need to invent a concurrent data structure at all.

Comment: I will investigate this.  Thank you.  I can do some design change but most of my day people pushing me for new features.

Comment: Thread-local variables, if available, require _fewer_ design changes than your proposed solution. They are faster because they were thought for the specific case of data keyed on thread IDs, and as a result there is special compiler, linker and processor support for them. They are simpler to use because you don't need to code and then access a homebrew data structure _at all_ (so all the code related to it disappears): Instead you can simply directly read from and assign to the variable, as though it were a global, except that each thread has its own copy. The prototypical example is `errno`.

Comment: I investigated thread local and agree this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  From wikipedia:

> In computing, memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.